# Why does IDA Pro's pseudocode function not produce for loops?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

Question came up in a reverse engineering class.  The prof asked this question.  I mean, in the grand scheme of things, while loops == for loops, I don't have a problem with that.

IDA Pro book... Google... not seeing anything online here.

So why does IDA pro never produce for loops in its pseudocode generator?

Comment: Why the downvote?  How is this question off-topic?  Wrong tags?

Comment: The question as stated is presented as an "obvious" fact without any evidence.

Comment: I wanted to say usually it produces do while loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you haven't seem them does not mean they don't exist. In my experience the decompiler produces `for` loops all the time.

**EDIT**: Here's just one example:

```
 loc_804B520:
                 xor     edx, edx
                 jmp     short loc_804B52B

 loc_804B524:
                 mov     al, [edi+edx]
                 mov     [ebx+edx], al
                 inc     edx

 loc_804B52B:
                 cmp     edx, esi
                 jl      short loc_804B524
```

Output:

```
  for ( i = 0; i < a2; ++i )
    *(_BYTE *)(v2 + i) = *(_BYTE *)(a1 + i);
```

Comment: Well, for the record the question came up in a reversing class, and no one had the answer.  The prof asked the question.

Comment: Well, the current question definitely does not mention it came from "the prof". Maybe you should rephrase your question and describe the full context.

Comment: I updated the context accordingly.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide an assembly blob that should be interpreted correctly as a for loop?

Answer (score 5):

The decompiler *can* produce `for` loops.

It uses the `Ctree` statement element [`cit_for`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/hexrays_8hpp_source.shtml#l00997) and the `Ctree` expression [`cfor_t`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/hexrays_8hpp_source.shtml#l01775) to represent these code constructs in the decompilation graph.